# Weird Error when upgrading from angularjs version 1.2 to 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I am trying to upgrade to angularjs 1.3 and stuck getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $compileProvider
```

I do have 'ngSanitize' loaded, and there are no file missing errors... Am I missing something?

Also this works perfectly with the 1.2 branch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need to see your code, can't do anything with just an error message

Comment: Do you have interceptors !

Comment: Is this a normal site or unit testing?

Comment: @VladimirFazilov did you resolve your problem because I'm having the same issue myself when I migrated from 1.2 to 1.3.